# WPF TreeView Children Nodes not shown on parent focus

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am using a TreeView control in my Application but I am having trouble understanding a basic concept. In some examples the tree is used like this:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header="Managers">
    <TextBlock Text="Michael" />
    <TextBlock Text="Paul" />
  </TreeViewItem>
  <TreeViewItem Header="Project Managers">
    <TextBlock Text="John" />
    <TextBlock Text="Tim" />
    <TextBlock Text="David" />
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

I used this but when I give focus to a Tree node containig children, The text of the children dissapears. What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use TextBlock for any reason you can do it like this.

```
    <TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Managers">
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Michael" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Paul" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Project Managers">
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="John" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Tim" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="David" />
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

To get a basic understanding of TreeView [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF) article might be helpful.

Comment: This one seems good. I put TextBlock as an example but I need a more complicated structure in each item, so with this approach it is possible. I choose this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurs due a style problem, you can solve this with the workaround bellow.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Managers">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Michael" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="Paul" />
    </TreeViewItem>
    <TreeViewItem Header="Project Managers">
        <TreeViewItem Header="John"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Tim" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="David" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```